# bitcoind inconsistent authentication error

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, authentication

I am using a Linux computer.
The issue I am having is that sometimes I have to use "kill -s 9 (bitcoind pid)" and restart bitcoind using "bitcoind -txindex" because bitcoind will sometimes not let me use "bitcoind stop". For example:

```
brian@brians-lair3:~/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc15$ bitcoind stop
error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)
```

This happens after bitcoind has been running for a few hours or so.
It also locks me out of bitcoin-cli:

```
brian@brians-lair3:~/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc15$ bitcoin-cli getinfo -rpcuser=b -rpcpassword=a
error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)
brian@brians-lair3:~/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc15$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)
```

Even when I specify the correct password and username it doesn't work.
Initially when I start bitcoind though, I can use bitcoin-cli:

```
brian@brians-lair3:~/Downloads/DownloadsArchive$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
{
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 352549,
    "timeoffset" : -1,
    "connections" : 26,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 49446390688.24143982,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1421427760,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "unlocked_until" : 0,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Also here is my bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcuser=b
rpcpassword=a
txindex=1
server=1
```

here is debug.log, its at this link:

```
1. goto 66.42.220.205:18809 (its a website) type that in URL box 
in a web browser

2. download debug.log
```

My question is can I prevent bitcoind from eventually coming to a point where I have to restart it using the command "kill -s 9 (pid)" and "bitcoind -txindex", or can I prevent it from coming into a state where it wont let me interact with it? If I can prevent this, how do I?

Also I need to use -txindex because it keeps an index of transactions and I need that for payment processing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the contents of `debug.log` at the point it crashes? Also why don't you update your bitcoin-core to the latest stable version (0.10.0)? On a side note, you don't need to explicitly pass the `-txindex` parameter since it's already defined inside `bitcoin.conf`.

Comment: I will update bitcoin and post the contents of debug.log

Comment: Odd. Is `bitcoin.conf` changing between bitcoin starting and when you have this problem?

Comment: From what I've seen bitcoin.conf hasn't changed. Also, the bug might have been patched in bitcoin 0.10.0 because from what I've seen, bitcoind hasn't rejected connection from bitcoin-cli since I updated bitcoin.

Comment: The error has happened again where bitcoind fails to authenticate connections correctly, even if you are unsure of an answer post what you can, my bitcoin payment processor will fail to work properly if bitcoind randomly denies access.